# Identifying when a file is changed- Bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So in my bash shell script, I have it running through a for loop. Inside the for loop, I use `find "$myarray[i]" >> $tmp` to look for a certain directory each time through the loop. Sometimes, it finds the variable in `myarray[i]` and sometimes it doesn't. When it does find something in `myarray[i]`, I want it to execute `echo "<br>" >> $tmp`. Is there a way for me to check whether `$tmp` has changed after executing the `find` line, so that I know when to execute the `echo "<br>" >> $tmp` line?

Comment: Is that find command going to find multiple things or only one thing? If it finds multiple things do you want a `<br>` after *each* thing it finds or only after all the things it finds?

Comment: I don't think `find "$myarray[i]"` does what you think it does.

Comment: Include some (pseudo) code please.

Comment: So the find command should find multiple things. `$myarray` is actually an array of directories, and in each directory it searches for all the subdirectories owned by a certain user. Each time it finishes finding all the subdirectories in `$myarray[i]`, it should execute an `echo "<br>" >> $tmp` if it finds any subdirectories owned by the user before moving onto `$myarray[i+1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store the output of `find`, and if non-empty, echo the line break:

```
found=$(find . -name "${myarray[i]}")
if [[ -n $found ]]; then
    { echo "$found"; echo "<br>"; } >> "$tmp"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is to take action whenever a filesystem event happens (such as a file update or directory creation), I'd avoid writing a custom polling loop.  Instead, use one of several tools created specifically for that use case.

The Linux tool "inotify" seems to be popular, and it has wrappers such as inotify-tools to make it easier to call from a command line.  There's also the cross-platform Python package "watchdog", the .NET/mono tool "System.IO.FileSystemWatcher", the OSX built-in utility "Folder Actions", "fswatch", and others.

It's easy to mess up polling, and hard to properly handle things like automatic restarts, unusual file names, and filesystem errors.  The purpose-specific tools were created because there's no good way to do it with a (simple) bash loop.